# CSS3: How to change style only after manual line break

Tags: html, list, css

I try to format a list: The first line should be bold, and the second line should not. But only, if the break is done manually:

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>This is a long list entry, and the second line should not be formated other than the first line, beacuse this looks stupid</li>
<li>This is a headline<br />After the line break, the text should not be bold anymore</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li::first-line {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kgf39vwk/

I can`t add more paragraphs or divs or something, because this is content edited by TinyMCE Editor, and it would be much more complex for the user, do do this formatting manually.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: With CSS you can't. (Only when adding an extra element). Are you in for a JS/ jQuery solution?

Comment: When there is no CSS solution, then a JS/JQuery solution is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any way to achieve this with just css. But you could use jQuery for this:

```
$('li').not(':has(br)').addClass('all_bold');
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kgf39vwk/2/

Comment: nice solution, no new elements need to be added. If nobody has another idea for a CSS solution, I will mark that answer as the accepted...

Comment: I hope it helped you, if you did not found any other answer, please mark this as accepted :D @user1383029